# How to select blanks in a column and then select those rows

Tags: excel

I know how to find all the blanks in my selected column. But I want to go a step further and select entire row of those found in first step.

So:

Step 1 - Find all blanks in a certain column
Step 2 - Select the rows found in step 1

Is this possible?

Comment: how would you select all the blanks in your column? That may lead naturally to how to approach step 2 :)

Comment: Press F5 > Special... > Blanks will select blanks in a selected column

Comment: with vba, use `specialcells(xlcelltypeblanks).entirerow`, otherwise, not possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This examines the column contain the *ActiveCell*

```
Sub dural()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveCell.EntireColumn)
    r.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Select
End Sub
```